# Помогите выяснить почему выдает ошибку "File "Путь", line 22, in __next__ if not self.my_list[self.cursor]: IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, index

Написать итератор, который принимает список списков, и возвращает их плоское представление, т.е последовательность состоящую из вложенных элементов.

Должен отпечататься каждый элемент каждого вложенного списка

```
'a' 
'b' 
'c' 
'd'
'e'
'f'
'h'
False
1
2
None
```

а комперхеншн, выражение вернет плоский список `flat_list = [item for item in FlatIterator(nested_list)]`

во `flat_list` должен быть такой список: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', False, 1, 2, None]`

Написать генератор, который принимает список списков, и возвращает их плоское представление

Должен отпечататься каждый элемент каждого вложенного списка

```
nested_list = [
            ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            ['d', 'e', 'f', 'h', False],
            [1, 2, None],
        ]
```

```
class FlatIterator:
    def __init__(self, n_l):
        self.my_list = n_l

    def __iter__(self):
        self.cursor = 0
        self.nest_cursor = -1
        self.full_list = []
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.nest_cursor += 1
        if len(self.my_list[self.cursor]) == self.nest_cursor:
            self.cursor += 1
            self.nest_cursor = 0
        if not self.my_list[self.cursor]:
            raise StopIteration
        self.full_list = self.my_list[self.cursor][self.nest_cursor]
        return self.full_list
```

```
def flat_generator(my_list):
    for my_list_o in my_list:
        for my_list_t in my_list_o:
            yield my_list_t
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in FlatIterator(nested_list):
        print(item)

    flat_list = [items for items in FlatIterator(nested_list)]
    print(flat_list)

    for item in flat_generator(nested_list):
        print(item)
```

Comment: `(k for x in nested_list for k in x)` - вот это уже генератор

Answer (score 0):

```
        if not self.my_list[self.cursor]:
            raise StopIteration
```

А что вы здесь проверяете? Что очередной перебираемый список пуст? У вас таких нет. Вам нужно проверять тут выход за пределы списка:

```
        if self.cursor >= len(self.my_list):
            raise StopIteration
```

Но вообще я не понял, зачем такие мучения с индексами, можно на основе генератора сделать класс-итератор:

```
class FlatIterator:
    def __init__(self, n_l):
        self.my_list = n_l

    def flat_generator(self):
        for my_list_o in self.my_list:
            for my_list_t in my_list_o:
                yield my_list_t
            
    def __iter__(self):
        self.iterator = iter(self.flat_generator())
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.iterator)
```